# SharePoint List not considering RowLimit CAML Tag - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, office365

I have a method in JavaScript that queries a list. Users are able to use some filters.
When I fetch all items of the list (when the form opens), the list is retrieved correct.
However, when I use some filter, in which some "or" clauses are added, I'm getting the following error message:

"Request failed. The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator"

It seems that the query are not considering my row limit. Before I perform the process of import the data (during my tests with a few data), this query were work well.

This is the XML that I'm generating to perform the operation:

```
<View>
   <Query>
      <Where>
         <And>
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name="AppvdSuppName" />
               <Value Type="Text">Non Approved Prime Supplier</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Or>
               <Contains>
                  <FieldRef Name="SuppCatName" />
                  <Value Type="Text">unit 7</Value>
               </Contains>
               <Contains>
                  <FieldRef Name="SuppName" />
                  <Value Type="Text">unit 7</Value>
               </Contains>
            </Or>
         </And>
      </Where>
   </Query>
   <RowLimit>30</RowLimit>
</View>
```

Can somebody help me to find a solution to this problem (I tried to create indexes for these columns, but it does not work).

Comment: Is the "It seems..." the actual error message?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to add the message (now, it was added).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can't use `<Contains>` to circumvent the list view threshold

`<Contains>` operations do not benefit from column indexing, and so do not help you circumvent the throttling put in place by the list view threshold (5000 items by default).

To explain why indexing doesn't help with "contains" operations, think about indexing like arranging books on a shelf in alphabetical order by title. (This is equivalent to applying indexing to the Title field.)

You could find a book with a specific title very quickly because you'd be able to skip to the spot where you know the book should be. In fact, you only need to know what the title *starts with* to find it quickly.

But what happens if you only know a portion of the title of the book you're looking for? Unless you know that the title starts with that text, the only way to find the book will be to look at every book, one at a time.

Just like putting books in alphabetical order doesn't help you find books that contain certain words, the `<Contains>` element in CAML cannot take advantage of column indexing. Comparison operations that **can** take advantage of column indexing include equality tests (`<Eq>`, `<Neq>`), inequality comparisons (`<Gt>`,`<Lt>`,`<Geq>`,`<Leq>`), and `<StartsWith>`.

### Alternative: Filtering on exact names

If you have applied indexing to the `SuppCatName` and `SuppName` columns, exact (`<Eq>`) filters in your CAML query for all possible valid values should be able to bypass the list view threshold, assuming the results themselves (after applying those filters) will not exceed the list view threshold of 5000 items.

If those two columns need to be open-ended for business reasons, consider storing the determining substring value in a different indexed field that you can better filter against.

This can't be a calculated field, unfortunately, since those cannot be indexed. But if you don't want to force the users to enter the new piece of data manually, you could use a workflow to set an indexed field's value based on the values in the `SuppCatName` and `SuppName` columns.

### Suggestion: Add an `<OrderBy>` element

The benefit of the `<RowLimit>` element is that it lets you get paged results. It's equivalent to saying "give me the first `x` items."

However, for that to be meaningful, you should tell SharePoint to sort the results. Otherwise "the first `x` items" is arbitrary (and probably sorted by the automatic ID field by default).

Comment: The second alternative worked fine, with a good performance. What i did was create an indexed column and, due to the fact that the data just for viewing, i filled these created column, with the values of the columns that i wanted to use the filter. Then, when i use my filters i just use a contains in this new field and the results are retrieved correctly. I've separated the values with a defined char, and, when i need some specific value, i just search for the value between this specific char. Well, for me it is an workaround, however, it was the way that worked for me. Thanks for answering.